# SQL in R Round Off Error

Tags: sql, r, rounding, rsqlite

I tried using the following sql query in R to round off all the numbers in one column of my Data frame.

```
sqldf("UPDATE myData SET Total = ROUND(Total, 2)")
```

I get the follwing error after firing the query:

```
In rsqlite_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries**
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Though I don't get that error, you are still missing the function of `sqldf` with `UPDATE` queries. See [`sqldf` FAQ #8](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update).

Comment: That is not an error. It is a warning and represents a bug in RSQLite that has been reported previously.  Either turn off warnings, ignore it or use an earlier version of RSQLite.  Note that `update` does not return anything so the statement won't do anything.  You need `sqldf(c("update ...", select * from myData"))` to actually get something back; however, that won't cause the warning to go away.

Comment: Thanks both. Issue resolved. It was a warning as Grothendieck said.